# PHP Timestamp from array

Tags: php, time, timestamp

I have timestamps in array like this: `20221206235959`

If I do this:

```
$start_time = $book->booking_start;
echo (date('F j, Y',$start_time));
```

Result is: `July 1, 642735`

How can I change it to something like this: `06.12.2022 23:59:59` ?

Comment: Timestamp is just a generic word for time. `date()` expects a **Unix time**, but you just have YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS without separators.

Comment: Hint: `echo DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHis', $start_time)->format("d.m.Y H:i:s");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to parse and format the input `datetime` value:

```
<?php
$start_time = '20221206235959';
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHis', $start_time)->format("d.m.Y H:i:s");
?>
```

Result:

```
06.12.2022 23:59:59
```